# How to set a member variable value using reflection in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, reflection

I've read through numerous tutorials and tried countless things to get this to work but can't seem to find a solution.

All I want to do is use reflection to set the value for a named member variable. I can **read** the values just fine, but how do I **write** a value?

Here is my sample code:

```
class MyObject
{
    public var myString : String = "Not working"
}

func test()
{
    let value = "It works!"
    let member = "myString"
    var myObject = MyObject()

    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: myObject)
    for (_, var attr) in mirror.children.enumerated() {
        if attr.label == member {
            print("Setting value of \(member)")

            // attempt to set the member variable value
            attr.value = value

            break
        }
    }

    print("New value: \(myObject.myString)")
}
```

Running this example, the output prints the old value of myString. I'm using Swift 4 for iOS.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot modify value with built-in `Mirror`.

Maybe try [Runtime](https://github.com/wickwirew/Runtime) named library instead (which's the successor of now deprecated [Reflection](https://github.com/Zewo/Reflection) library).

**OR**

You can make it without reflection if it is acceptable for you, like:

```
class MyObject: NSObject {
    @objc public var myString : String = "Not working"
}

func test() {
    let value = "It works!"
    let member = "myString"
    let myObject = MyObject()
    
    myObject.setValue(value, forKey: member)
   
    print("New value: \(myObject.myString)")
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: It works! Thank you! I had tried this before but it looks like the thing I was missing was "@objc" in the variable declaration. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

> Swift's reflection capabilities are based around a `struct` called
>   `Mirror`. You create a mirror for a particular `subject` and the
>   mirror will then let you query it.

Means with `Mirror` you can not modify the `subject` in your case `MyObject`.

Read [HERE](https://appventure.me/2015/10/24/swift-reflection-api-what-you-can-do/) for more info.

**EDIT:**

You can simply update your class property as shown below:

```
func test() {

    let myObject = MyObject()
    myObject.myString = "It works!"
    print("New value: \(myObject.myString)") // "New value: It works!"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What do I use then to write to the variable?

Comment: Not sure about your requirement but you can simple update `myString` with `myObject.myString = "It works!"`